# sql order by doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I have code like this:

```
function artykul_firmy_z_branzy($art_id, $limit) {
    return select("
        select f.id from artykuly a, firmy f where a.display = true
        and a.id_branzy = f.branza_id and a.id = :id and f.profil <> 0 order by f.profil desc, f.firma asc limit ${limit}
    ", array('id' => $art_id));
}
```

This code should choose some rows from sql database and sort it, and it works great, but result, which has the biggest "f.profil" is always on the end of list, when I change limit to "1", then I got only this result with biggest f.profil, so ordering works, but how to show this on the first position?

Code in template, which shows results:

```
{% if firmy_z_branzy_logo %}
                <div class="firmy-z-branzy">
                    <img src="/static/screw.png" class="label-screw" /> <div class="label-title">FIRMY Z TEJ BRANŻY</div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>

                    {% for i in firmy_z_branzy_logo %}
                        <div class="firma-branza"><a href="/wizytowka/{{ i.id_firmy }}"><img src="/{{ i.sciezka }}m/{{ i.plik }}" / style="margin-bottom:6px;"></a>{{ i.opis }}</div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
```

Comment: I'd say to use `JOIN` on your select instead of listing them all... Also, have you tried removing the `f.firma asc`?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing f.firma asc or f.profil desc to see if this works with only one order, but it isn't changing anything. The problem is that, it works corectly - it picks from the database, for example, 12 (limit) results with biggest f.profil, but on website it shows this 12 highest results in random order.
for example: "a(5), b(3), c(9), d(5), e(1)" - my code must pick 3 highest numbers and show this sorted by the highest, but i got something like: "a(5),c(9),d(5)" - without sort, but correctly picked.

Comment: That's weird... I don't know how this works, here is screen how changing this code affect on results - http://i.imgur.com/iugQwos.jpg At the bottom of this image I presented how I want to sort this results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try with this INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT a.*, f.* FROM artykuly a 
INNER JOIN firmy f ON a.id_branzy = f.branza_id AND a.display = true AND a.id = :id AND f.profil <> 0
ORDER BY f.profil desc, f.firma LIMIT ${limit}
```

Comment: The results are the same as before - correct pick but unsorted.

Comment: If you put the query into phpMyAdmin it still returns wrong?

Comment: in phpMyAdmin results are correctly sorted, just as I want.